# Watermark image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, watermark

I have image field, and im trying to get watermark on it, while hovering this image. I tried simple img:hover, but the hover image still under my main img. Any ideas how can i make my hover image to be higher then my main img.

Comment: Could you post a JS Fiddle for it.

Comment: ++ Code snippets or link to working samples would help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xxuHX/   Thats not exactly my code, i'm creating drupal project, but its the way im trying to create

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/2UQ6N/

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
    <img src="http://cdn-img.easyicon.cn/png/270/27093.png" class="watermark" />
</div>

div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div:hover img.watermark {
    display: block;
}

img.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .6;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i have one more question regarding this code. My image is .5 opacity while not hover, and 1.0 on hover. But when i moving my cursor from main image to hover image, opacity dissapears. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the hover image later in the document flow or increase the `z-index` to be higher than the image it is covering.

As people will no doubt mention, this will not stop people from getting hold of your image if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a position: relative to put an image on top.

```
<img src="images/image1" width="225" height="219" border="0"> 


<img src="images/image2" width="250" height="372" border="0" style="position: relative;>
```

So on your :hover you add the position: relative to your top image.